# Detect repeated sequences of numbers in an array

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, sequence

I thought this was easy but frankly its not.

Given some lists like these:

```
([15,3,15,3, 15, 40])
([15,15,3,15,15,40])
([6,3,5,17,19,15,13,15,6,3,5,3])
```

if the pattern from the first sequence is detected then the output list should increment each number position like this:

```
[15,3,15,3, 15, 40] => [0,0,1,2, 0,0]
[15,15,3,15,15,40] => [0,0,0,1,2,0]
```

Basically, there is an output list the size of input list. Each number is looked at and when a sequence is detected to be repeating the counter will increment once, starting at 0 and keep incrementing till the end of the pattern. If the sequence repeats again, the counter will increment further.

I have tried some code but its not solving this problem.

For eg,
[15,3, 15,3,15,40], it 
stores the numbers not seen. 
Since at index 2, 15 is repeated, it checks whether index[2+1] == index[0+1]
if so increment to 1 and move to next number. Now index[3+1] != [1+1] and index [3+1] is the same as the first number of current number where condition was detected( in this case index[2] is already covered. Hence, the last repeating number is 3 and increment is 2 thus giving [0,0,1,2,0,0];

I don't know whether to run a loop to check this and search for the sub-list where the pattern is repeating till violation in a smaller loop;

One logic I thought of was:

1. If number not in seen map, add to map/dictionary with index position;
2. Else find the last position in array where it was first detected and compare the next position with the last position + i [i=1..n until the first detected number is not repeated again OR the next number != the next number from the last next number]
3. Increment all detected number positions.

Comment: What does the the array of numbers represent in you project ? What are you trying to achieve ? `if the pattern from the first sequence is detected` What pattern ? Detected where ? In the same list ? in one of the other lists ? `Each number is looked at and when a sequence is detected to be repeating the counter will increment once` Why does the counter is incremented ? What are we trying to count here ?

Comment: By "the sequence" you mean any sub-sequence of any size? SO, for instance, any number previously seen is a size-1 repeated seq?

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin Too many questions. im updating the question for you.

Comment: @TimothéeJeannin Too many questions. im updating the question for you.